Rbind for tables with duplicate row names
I have two tables that I would like to combine to create a summary table
df1 <- data.frame(median=c(151, 98, 125, 47),
                             Q25=c(148, 90, 120, 44),
                             Q75=c(158, 104, 132, 53),
                  pass_or_fail=c('pass')
                             )
row.names(df1)<-c("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4")

df2 <- data.frame(median=c(148, 95, 135, 40),
                             Q25=c(140, 88, 130, 35),
                             Q75=c(150, 100, 141, 45),
                  pass_or_fail=c('fail')
                             )
row.names(df2)<-c("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4")



rbind(df1, df2)

The output I am looking for is shown below, where the rownames shared between the 2 dataframes, columns are grouped by "pass" or "fail", and the value is shown as the median with IQR in brackets

The result of the rbind is altered row names as duplicate names are not allowed. I am wondering how I can overcome the issue of the rownames being renamed, and if the IQR can be shown in brackets using kable or another function.

library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(rownames_to_column(df1), 
          rownames_to_column(df2)) %>% 
  mutate(stat = paste0(median, " (", Q25, "-", Q75, ")"), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = pass_or_fail, values_from = stat) %>% 
  column_to_rownames()

#>                 pass          fail
#> param1 151 (148-158) 148 (140-150)
#> param2   98 (90-104)   95 (88-100)
#> param3 125 (120-132) 135 (130-141)
#> param4    47 (44-53)    40 (35-45)

Created on 2024-07-07 with reprex v2.0.2

Some cbind fun, using a blank df1[0] to ensure the rownames are retained:
cbind(
    df1[0],
    pass = with(df1,
                paste0(median, " (", Q25, "-", Q75, ")")),
    fail = with(df2[rownames(df1),],
                paste0(median, " (", Q25, "-", Q75, ")"))
)
#                pass          fail
#param1 151 (148-158) 148 (140-150)
#param2   98 (90-104)   95 (88-100)
#param3 125 (120-132) 135 (130-141)
#param4    47 (44-53)    40 (35-45)


Using sprintf with do.call.
> sapply(list(df1[-4], df2[-4]), \(x) do.call('sprintf', c('%s (%s-%s)', x))) |> 
+   `dimnames<-`(list(rownames(df1[-4]), unique(c(df1[, 4], df2[, 4])))) |> 
+   as.data.frame()
                pass          fail
param1 151 (148-158) 148 (140-150)
param2   98 (90-104)   95 (88-100)
param3 125 (120-132) 135 (130-141)
param4    47 (44-53)    40 (35-45)


Data:
> dput(df1)
structure(list(median = c(151, 98, 125, 47), Q25 = c(148, 90, 
120, 44), Q75 = c(158, 104, 132, 53), pass_or_fail = c("pass", 
"pass", "pass", "pass")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("param1", 
"param2", "param3", "param4"))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(median = c(148, 95, 135, 40), Q25 = c(140, 88, 
130, 35), Q75 = c(150, 100, 141, 45), pass_or_fail = c("fail", 
"fail", "fail", "fail")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("param1", 
"param2", "param3", "param4"))

